# Custom order for a loop in Grav CMS (uses Twig)

Tags: twig, grav

I'm listing all the pages (from different folders) belonging to category "featured", and I'd like to order them by a custom value. At the moment they're being ordered by date:

```
{% for p in taxonomy.findTaxonomy({'category':'featured'}).order('date','desc') %} 
    {{ p.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

However I want to add an "order" field in the page header

```
---
// for the first page to show
title: Just a page
order: 1 
---
// for the second page to show
title: Not just a page
order: 2
---
```

What I want is something like .order('p.header.order','asc')

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got help from @rhukster at Grav forums but posting the solution here as well. It's simple.

```
.order('header.order','asc')
```

Answer (score 0):

grav has the option to order folders by adding a number at the beginning of the folder name.

Comment: I know, but as far as I understood it doesn't work for this case since I'm listing pages from different folders by the category